# Macro Extension Rings

Tags: macro, olympus, extension-tubes

Hi Folks I have a Olympus E410.  I recently purchased Macro extension rings, but they do not seem to work.  When I fitted them to my camera everything was blurred, whether one inch away or two feet away.  What am I doing wrong?  Or should I ask what am I not doing?
I am using the bog standard lens that came with the camera 17.5-45mm.
I would appreciate any advice from some of you experts on here. 
Regards Len G

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the lens used and the amount of extension it may not be possible to achieve focus at all. When you use extension rings you lose the ability to focus at infinity in exchange for the ability to focus behind the lens' normal minimum focusing distance. However, the new maximum focusing distance could be behind the front element of the lens if you use too much extension.

Start with the smallest extension ring and try to focus. If you need more magnification then add more extension incrementally. Keep in mind your minimum/maximum focusing distances may change based on your focal length.

You may also want to consider that at macro distances a wide open aperture is often not sufficient for a sharp image. You may want to start at F/8 or F/11 to get enough depth of field.